# Error : (Input index file full.idx not found. Usage: makeindex ). I am using texstudio editor

Tags: indexing, texstudio, jabref

I am using Texstudio editor.  I am using Latex to write my thesis. 
I have had no problem in the past that Latex list the references in my thesis write-up successfully. Suddenly, when I added one more reference (bibtex), and did the indexing for the references using the shortcut F12, I got the following error:

```
Process started: makeindex.exe "full".idx

Input index file full.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty]
  [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Process exited with error(s)
```

I already tried the solution here but It did not work for my case!

- [Makeindex no .nls file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161304/makeindex-no-nls-file)
- [Texmaker and MacTex are unable to compile Index, Nomenclature and Biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145843/texmaker-and-mactex-are-unable-to-compile-index-nomenclature-and-biber)

I hope that you help me in solve my problem.

Comment: you have tagged the question bibtex (about the references `\cite` etc) but the error is about `makeindex` (`\index` `\printindex` etc) did you just run makeindex instead of bibtex?

Comment: I have an update. The Texstudio now tells me something els. IT is: This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning input file full.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in full.ind. Transcript written in full.ilg. I am trying to fix this now.

Comment: If your document doesn't contain `\makeindex` you shouldn't be trying to run `makeindex file.idx` (as David has indicated).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it as follows: Same error message appeared when I tried to compile my text. I rebooted my pc (Windows 10 and its updates, you know...), I read threads everywhere and tried what they said but nothing. Then...i realized that I, with no intention, had changed the function of the "Quick compilation" button and I was, since the problem popped up, trying to run a MakeIndex!

Comment: It sounds like this is the most likely cause. Could you add to your answer to indicate how to change the action of the "Quick compilation" button so that it doesn't run `makeindex`.